# display only if a matrix cell has a certain value

Tags: matrix

have this table that I want to display only if one parameter set in a matrix cell has a value of 1:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{canale_corrente}" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}         
                                {formati_prodotti}
                                    {if enable_shop_lnk == "1"}

                                    <div class="small-12 column">
                                        <div class="content-box">
                                            <h2>TITLE</h2>
                                            <p class="subhead">SUBTITLE</p>
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Formato</td>
                                                        <td>Shop</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>{codice_formato} - {nome_formato}</td>
                                                        <td><a href="#" class="tiny button radius">BUY</a></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {/if}
                                {/formati_prodotti}
                            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

CAPTION:

{formati_prodotti} is a matrix field

enable_shop_lnk is a child field inside {formati_prodotti} that can be 0 or 1

the problem is that I can't find a way to hide the entire table when there's no records with enable_shop_lnk == 0

Also because the enable_shop_link is inside a matrix field I can check it only by wrapping it with the matrix field {formati_prodotti} and if there's more than one entry meeting the criteria I get more than one table!

Any idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the whole {formati_prodotti} tag pair in this conditional:

```
{if '{formati_prodotti:total_rows search:enable_shop_lnk="1"}'}
    {formati_prodotti}
        ...
    {/formati_prodotti}
{/if}
```

See http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/templating/field.html#total-rows

Comment: wonderfull Brandon!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{if "{enable_shop_lnk}" == "1"}
```

Regard's.

Comment: the conditional is working perfectly the real problem is that this field is a matrix child and I can check it only wrapping it inside the matrix tag so for example if there are 3 products i get 3 different tables!